# Query DBPedia to get all books of an author

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

```
SELECT ?book
WHERE {
  ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
  ?book WHAT_PREDICATE 'Agatha Christie'
}
```

I want to know what predicate to use in the query. I haven't found any list with books or writers predicates on **DBPedia**.

Comment: I need some kind of `isWrittenBy` property here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ?book
WHERE {
  ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
  ?book dbpprop:author ?author .
  ?author dbpprop:name ?name
  FILTER regex(?name, "Agatha Christie", "i")
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://dbpedia.org/page/Agatha_Christie) is the complete list of properties.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the URI (`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agatha_Christie`) instead of the regex filter?

Comment: @unor As you said, not for this small example. But in my project I have a reason. Good tip.

And, for further clarification, I'm not using DBPedia anymore. Freebase gives me more results for books and writers.

Comment: @felipe.zkn If you solved your problem, be sure to accept your answer.